# Hide specifics elements from "Add media" in WP

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Trying to hide some elements "actions" from the "Add Media" window.
the thing is, I need to hide those actions in a specific post type

Tried the following snippet, of course not working

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_head', function () { ?>
<style>
    
    .media-menu-item #menu-item-featured-image {
    display: none;
    }

</style>
<?php } );
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only mistake is that the id "menu-item-featured-image" is not a child for the class "media-menu-item", but it is the same element

[image]

so just delete the space between ".media-menu-item" and "#menu-item-featured-image"

```
.media-menu-item#menu-item-featured-image {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: You also need to change your add_action function for apply to admin area from wp_head to admin_head  add_action('admin_head')

Comment: Thanks! that did it! :)